# ¿Hacer consulta a dos tablas diferentes y mostrar en la vista de blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tabla 1 noticias
Tabla 2 notas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El siguiente controlador hace una consulta a la tabla noticias.
El buscador hace la consulta con tres campos diferentes.
La pregunta   es como hacer la consulta desde la tabla (notas) a la vez que la tabla noticias. Para después mostrar los datos en la vista.

```html
// public function busqueda(Request $request)
// {
//
//   $ntc_turno = $request->input('noticiero_turno');
//   if($ntc_turno){
//     $noticia = Noticia::where('noticiero_turno','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")
//     ->orWhere('noticiero_programa','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")
//     ->orWhere('noticiero_fecha','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")
//
//     ->paginate(2);
//
//     return view('noticia.listar',array('noticia'=>$noticia));
//   }else{
//     $noticia = Noticia::paginate(3);
//     return view('noticia.listar',array('noticia'=>$noticia));
//
//   }
//
//
// }
```

Vista
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CÓDIGO DE LA VISTA**

```html
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')

<div class="panel panel-success">
  <div class="panel-heading">Buscar</div>
  <form action="/noticia/buscar" method="get" onsubmit="return showLoad()">
  <div class="panel-body">
   <label class="label-control">Buscar</label>
   <input type="text" name="noticiero_turno" class="form-control" placeholder="Please input stock name/description" required="required">
   <br>

 </div>
 <div class="panel-footer">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Buscar</button>
 </div>
 </form>
</div>
@if (isset($noticias))
   <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">Resultado de busqueda</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

     <div class='table-responsive'>
       <table class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>ID</th>
             <th>Turno</th>
             <th>Fecha</th>

          <th>nombre_nota</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
     @foreach($noticia as $buscar)
     <tr>
      <td>{{$buscar['noticiero_programa']}}</td>
      <td>{{$buscar['noticiero_turno']}}</td>
      <td>{{$buscar['noticiero_fecha']}}</td>


      <tr/>






       @endforeach

    <tr>

    </tr>


    </tbody>




   </table>
<center></center>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
  <a href="{{url('noticia/buscar')}}" class="btn btn-warning">Reiniciar busqueda</a>
  </div>
</div>
@endif

@if (isset($noticia))
   <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">Resultado de busqueda</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

     <div class='table-responsive'>
       <table class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>ID</th>
             <th>Turno</th>
             <th>Fecha</th>

          <th>nombre_nota</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
     @foreach($noticia as $buscar)
     <tr>
      <td>{{$buscar['noticiero_programa']}}</td>
      <td>{{$buscar['noticiero_turno']}}</td>
      <td>{{$buscar['noticiero_fecha']}}</td>
 <td>{{$buscar['nombre_nota']}}</td>

      <tr/>






       @endforeach
@endif

@stop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumo que tienes una relación creada con Eloquent de esta manera:

Nota:

```
class Nota extends Model
{
  ...

  public function noticia() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Noticia', 'noticia_id');
  }
}
```

Noticias:

```
class Noticia extends Model
{
  ...

  public function notas() {
    return $this->hasMany('Nota', 'noticia_id');
  }
}
```

Para hacer la consulta en ambas tablas "al tiempo", usaremos whereHas (consulta en la relación) y orWhere:

```
Noticia::with('notas')
->whereHas('notas', function($query) use($ntc_turno) {
    $query->where('nombre_nota','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%"));
})
->orWhere('noticiero_turno','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%");
->orWhere('noticiero_programa','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%");
->orWhere('noticiero_fecha','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%");
->paginate(2);
```

Más información en la documentación de Eloquent:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Efectivamente las relaciónes con eloquent esta definidos de esa manera, al momento de  probarlo tira Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'whereHas' (T_STRING). La versión que estoy usando es la 5.4.

Comment: Faltó el -> , ya lo corregí

Comment: Tira Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' en la linea de  $query->where('nombre_nota','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")); pero los parentesis los veo correctos que podría ser?

Comment: Hay un paréntesis adicional al final.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) corregido el paréntesis me aparece  ese error, la verdad no sé si lo implemente correctamente [https://photos.app.goo.gl/ocJPeZ40QVWgneVx2]